# How to filter json in javascript, parse.com

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I have "fetch"ed my data and displayed the data just fine. Now i would like to filter the data that is displayed. How do i filter my json data by one of the attributes?
When i run the code below my 'blogs' collections is undefined. I also could fetch of get my parse.com data filtered but i have not found out to do either successfully. thanks for your help.

```
this.blogs.fetch({
                    success: function(blogs) {
                        var blogs = blogs.filter(function(i){ 
                            console.log(i.empRequesting);
                            return i.empRequesting === userN;
                        });
                        console.log(blogs);
                        //blogsFiltered = $(blogs).filter(function(item){return item.empRequesting == userN;});
                        var blogsAdminView = new BlogsAdminView({ 
                            // Pass in current username to be rendered in #admin-tpl
                            username: Parse.User.current().get('username'),
                            collection: blogs
                        });
                        blogsAdminView.render();
                        $('.main-container').html(blogsAdminView.el);
                    },
                    error: function(blogs, error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            },
```

Comment: One best-practice note: don't reassign your argument variable. Let's make that `var blogsFiltered = blogs.filter(/* ... */);`. Where is `userN` defined? If that doesn't match any of the `empRequesting` attributes on your available blogs, nothing will be in the filtered array.

Comment: i believe the line you are referring is the line that is commented out. as it stands this returns an empty array. I know that the "empRequesting" field does exist and userN is returning the correct name. also the "console.log(i.empRequesting) returns undefined. Do you have any other helpful tips?

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about the first line in the function body, where you start with `var blogs = blogs.filter`. If logging `i.empRequesting` gives you `undefined` every time, and `userN` is defined, then all of the items in `blogs` are going to be filtered out.

Comment: yes, i see that happening. how do i call the "empRequesting" (field)data from json?